# Jenkins pipeline java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChildren

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to run a Pipeline job from Jenkinsfile (with Groovy code) but I am getting the following error -

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChildren
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:860)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:778)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
    at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1777)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1354)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor101.invoke(Unknown Source)
...
```

The code I am trying to execute is -

```
def getDataVersionFromNexus() {
    def user = params.nexusUser
    def password = params.nexusPassword    
    ...

    def oldVersion = -1
    print output
    if (!output.isEmpty()) {        
        def xmlContent = new XmlSlurper().parseText(output)
        oldVersion = "${xmlContent.versioning.release}"
    }

    return oldVersion
}
```

I have tried to annotate the method as `@NonCPS` (as suggested in a similar SO post) but then I don't get proper output.

Comment: Which line of your code causing the issue, it is not clear from the above question.

Comment: From the error looks like it is the use of XmlSlurper. Stack trace shows at `sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor101.invoke(Unknown Source)`

Answer (score 1):

Try to copy this value as list to ArrayList, then use.
For example, like this:

```
tmp = xmlContent.versioning.release.toList()
list = new ArrayList()
for (i = 0; i != tmp.size(); i += 1) {
    list.add(tmp.get(i))
}
oldVersion = list.get(0)
```